# Show that order of a Group is 2

Tags: group-theory, monoid

For a group $(G,*,I)$ if $a,b \in G$ such that $a * b$ has order 2.
I need to prove that $b * a$ has order 2.

---

*My Work:-*

$a * b$ has order 2 means $(a * b)^2 =I$ ,

so i need to prove is  $(b * a)^2 =I$

$b * a * b * a =I$     $\qquad$ { expanding it  }

$ a * b * a =b^{-1} * I$

$ a * b * a * b =b^{-1} * I * b$

$ a * b * a * b =b^{-1} * b$

$ a * b * a * b =I$

$ (a * b)^2 =I$

$ I =I$     $\qquad$ { given is $(a * b)^2 =I$  }

---

*Have I proved it in a correct way?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort of; it's kind of backward.  You should start with what is known, and work toward your end goal.  Otherwise, if you apply a non-invertible operation to both sides, you could end up with a specious proof.

$$
(a * b)^2 = I
$$
$$
a * b * a * b = I
$$
\begin{align}
b * a * b * a * b & = b * I \\ & = b
\end{align}
\begin{align}
b * a * b * a & = b * a * b * a * b * b^{-1} \\ & = b * b^{-1} \\ & = I
\end{align}